# Histogram of Image in Frequency Domain

Tags: python, image, image-processing, fft, wavelet

I have been trying to analyze the presence of low and high-frequency waves in images. My objective is to visually be able to discern if an image is composed majorly by low frequencies of high frequencies.

My first instinct is to generate a histogram of the Fourier Transform or Wavelet Transform of a color image. I'm, however, not sure how to proceed with that.

Given that the intensity of the Fourier transform gives no representation of the frequency, I thought I could generate a "histogram" using the coordinates as my 'bins' and the intensity as my frequency. But I'm not sure if this is mathematically sound.

Has any default way of creating a frequency-domain histogram been set? For this purpose, would wavelets or Fourier transform work best?

Thank you all for your help.

### Edit 1

So I've been trying to visualize individual frequencies that make up the fourier transform of an Image. But to no success.

I have tried to, for each point of the transformed image, reverse the transform with the remaining of the matrix set to zeroes, but I do not think the result is what I was expecting. Here are some examples:

[image: Input Image and Fourier Transforms for each channel.]

That's my initial image and it's channels fourier transform, ignore the red sky. Below are the Inverse Transform of some of the points, I use the following method to extract the frequencies. *`r_fft`* is not shifted.

```
wave_fft_r = np.zeros(r_fft.shape, dtype=r_fft.dtype)
wave_fft_r[i,j] = r_fft[i,j]
wave_img = np.fft.ifft2(wave_fft_r)
```

[image: Inverse Transform of single points.]

I do not think that helps analysing if a image is composed more of high-frequencies or low-frequencies. @CrisLuengo mentioned 1D representation of the frequencies, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Given the image below, for example, it seems like it has more high-frequencies than the first one, but I'm looking for a way to show that numerically. And only by looking at the magnitude spectrum it's not easy to differentiate that.
[image: Input Image 2]

Comment: a call to FFT returns an array where each element is assigned a frequency typically starting at frequency zero for element zero ... as you iterate across this array each array element is called a frequency bin ... the freq increment between each array element can be calculated

Comment: A histogram gives counts of specific items or groups of items. You don’t want that. What you want is to show the power of each frequency component. The FFT does exactly that. Not sure why you think you need to transform it. Maybe you are looking for a 1D representation of the 2D FFT of your image?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think that is exactly what I'm trying to do. To show the individual waves that generate the image.